# How to ping from a client in the network to a server not in the network connected on different interfaces on same linux box

Tags: linux-networking, embedded-linux

I am working on one Linux box. I want something like this.

network--->wlan0---->eth0-->other server.

Both wlan0 and eth0 interface reside inside same Linux box. I am using dhcp which is assigning something say 192.168.3.21 to my wlan0 interface.
I am assigning static IP say 192.168.3.101 to my eth0 interface and 192.168.3.102 to other server.
Now, I want to ping from the network(192.168.3.XX) to other server at the address of 192.168.3.102 and my eth0 at 192.168.3.101. I am unable to do so.

I am not even able to ping my other server at 192.168.3.102 from my linux box.

I have enabled ip forwarding via "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" command.

I have used the following command to enable nat forwarding too.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Still I am unable to ping.

Please, let me know what I am missing.
Any help will be so much appreciated.

Here is the output of iptables-save :-

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [481:39595]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [325:24634]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:229]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:229]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [482:39927]
:INPUT ACCEPT [474:38801]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [325:24634]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [325:24634]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [63:6229]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Feb 19 10:17:54 2018
```

Here is my output for ip route:-

default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  metric 10
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.190
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.235

Comment: Please show output for `iptables-save`.

Comment: Maybe your netmasks clash. Please edit to add output of `ip route`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a **router** with two interfaces, they need to be on separate subnets (example 192.168.0.0/24 is separate from 192.168.5.0/24). You have a clash here, visible in your `ip route`, it won't work.

If you want to use the same subnet on both interfaces, it's not a router, it's a two-port switch, which is commonly called a **bridge**.

- You could create one bridging interface and assign one IP there, possibly via DHCP.
- The wlan0 and eth0 should be left without IP addresses, they become transparent members of a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

To connect two different networks, one need to use bridge like below:

## Create the bridge interface

```
brctl addbr br0
```

## Add interfaces to the bridge

```
brctl addif eth0

brctl addif wan0
```

## Zero IP the interfaces.

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig wan0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
```

## Enable the bridge interface

```
ifconfig br0 10.0.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.1.255
```